# How to get the clock when clicking on a button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a contact form and a message list or primitive inbox where all messages is showing.
When i click on the button for "sending" the message, then it is retrieving the values from the textboxes and put it into a table.
I have to sort the messages, so the old messages appears in the top. 
Do I need to get the current clock when clicking on a button? or are there another way to do this?

### Example.

The contact: - a bit small

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxContactForeName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxContactMessage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

The list

```
<p> <% # Eval("Forename") %> </p>
<p> <% # Eval("Message") %> </p>
```

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Contact] ([Forename], [Message]) VALUES (@Forename, @Message)";

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Forename", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBoxContactForeName.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Message", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBoxContactMessage.Text;

    conn.Open();
    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() != 0)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Your message is send";
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Something went wrong";
    }
    conn.Close();
```

Comment: You should **always** be putting in example code. This question is very vague.

Comment: How should i know? it doesn't stand anywhere, i'm looking at other questions and there is no examples, but thx.

Comment: While saving the message in table add an extra field that holds the timestamp at which table entry was made. Use this time stamp for sorting.

Comment: Well, at least one understands the problem.. so all these voting down, should turn it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to add an additional column to your table, say 'time' or 'timestamp'

in your SQL Insert statement add this additional column and pass DateTime.Now() to the table in the database.

wherever you have sql query to retrieve the messages add an order by timestamp asc and you should see the oldest message displayed first on the messages list.

Answer (score 0):

U trying make this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp  ?

var d = new Date();

var n = d.getDate();

Comment: Well yeah, but i need to get the clock, and im working in asp, so im using less JavaScript as i think i need to use codebehind, as i need to order the messages as how old they are.